# Headless UI Combobox Focus Behavior

Tags: input, autocomplete, focus, remix.run, headless-ui

I am using the Headless UI Combobox as an autocomplete search bar (React/Remix app). I would like the search bar to give up focus after the search is submitted.

On some devices (e.g. iPhone Safari) it seems to do this by default; however, on desktop Chrome I get very different behavior. The combobox refocuses and I cant figure out when/why it is doing this, so I can't manually blur it in a useEffect.

All I could do to hack it was blur the bar on a setTimeout.

Comment: As a side note, it seems that when the focus is re-applied, on some browsers (e.g. safari) the cursor goes to the end as you would expect, but in others (e.g. chrome) the cursor goes to the beginning of the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and found a solution that may not be the most elegant but it does the job.

First, I added a ref to the ComboBox input element and used a setTimeout with a delay of 0 to blur it:

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
  // other stuff
  setTimeout(() => {
    searchRef.current.blur()
  }, 0)
}

// a structure like this
<ComboBox onChange={handleChange}>
  <Combobox.Input ref={searchRef} />
</ComboBox>
```

This worked fine for keyboard input, but I noticed that when I clicked on the ComboBox, it would immediately focus and then blur due to the setTimeout, creating a noticeable blinking effect. To fix this, I added an onMouseDown event to the ComboBox and called preventDefault() to prevent the input from being focused:

```js
<Combobox.Options
  onMouseDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }}
/>
```

Like you said it's kinda hacky but it works and after working on it for several hours, it working is better than it not working plus I don't get paid so no one will look at the code anyway.

Comment: Thank you for checking out my post! Yeah, I just setTimeout with a delay of 200 and didn't need the onMouseDown, but I think I like your solution better! Would like to see if anyone knows a bit more about what's going on under the hood of headless UI though. It seems to do a lot that it doesn't tell us about in the docs.

Comment: After adding the prevent default works but I am facing a new issue. If I type something and try to select an option by clicking on the item, it doesn't select the item.

Answer (score -1):

just modify this meta tag on your website head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```